# Prevent Wildfly from redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS

Tags: https, http, jboss, wildfly

I have a project running on Wildfly 15. For one scenario I need to disable HTTP requests being redirected to HTTPS. When I run the web application on localhost everything is fine, but when I replace localhost with my IP, the HTTP request is redirected to HTTPS.! What configuration do I need to change to make it work properly?

This is part of my standalone.xml:

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" enable-http2="true"/>
    <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
        <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    </host>
</server>
```

Comment: I dont know anything but even me guess you should look at words like https, socket-binding in your standalone.xml , remove https-listener tag and check is it works. Am i right? At least you should check documentation. https://docs.wildfly.org/21/Admin_Guide.html#server-configuration think, read, try

Comment: redirect-socket  https://docs.wildfly.org/21/Admin_Guide.html#http-connector

Comment: Maybe you use http proxy